# File keeps with .pending while flink bucketingsink job is cancelled with savepoint

Tags: apache-flink

We are using BucketingSink to write compressed file(seperate by "\n") to hdfs. However once we manually cancel the job, the last line of file will be truncated. If we cancel the job with savepoint everything is ok but the file is remaining .pending state. How to make those files completing renaming? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the .pending files was in the checkpointed list, u just need restart the job, then the .pending will be rename to the final name to commit.
If the .pending files were not in the checkpointed list, that is, the .pending files could be discarded, the flink will not do anything to it, neglected them is a good idea.

Try reading [This Blog Post](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html), then reading the source code of [BucketingSink](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-filesystem/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.java), you will know why and how to do that.